# Remove unnecessary margin in epslatex/gnuplot

Tags: latex, gnuplot

I would like to remove unnecessary margins (gray part in the figure below) in a PDF figure generated by epslatex (gnuplot).

[image]

Following are scripts and commands to create the figure.

```
set term epslatex standalone
set output "figure.tex"

set xlabel "\\LARGE $x$"
set ylabel "\\LARGE $y$"
set format x "\\Large{%.1f}"
set format y "\\Large{%.1f}"

set key left top Left
set size square

set xrange [0.0:1.0]
set yrange [0.0:1.0]

plot x     with lines dt 1 lw 5.0 lc rgb "red"   title "\\Large $y = x$",\
     x*x   with lines dt 2 lw 5.0 lc rgb "green" title "\\Large $y = x^2$",\
     x*x*x with lines dt 3 lw 5.0 lc rgb "blue"  title "\\Large $y = x^3$"
```

and commands

```
$ gnuplot sample.gp
$ pdflatex figure.tex
```

Instead of `pdflatex`, `xelatex` would also work. I would like to directly convert to PDF file.

It will be super good if we can remove these margins without too much effort (such as removing the margin manually one-by-one).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share `figure.tex`?

Comment: epslatex is a very old driver. More recent drivers have other customization flags. For instance `tightboundingbox` in the lua tikz driver. Alternatively, why not use `pdfcrop` to fix the bounding box issue?

Comment: @samcarter: thank you, but "figure.tex" is just a long list describing the graph appearance since I am now using `standalone` mode

Comment: @AlainMerigot: thank you very much. I was not aware of tikz driver, but it seems really good! I will try to use it. `pdfcrop` worked, but the command cropped also some part of the figure.... it might work out if I specify the parameter manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check `help latex`, it will tell you that default size is 5 x 3 inches. 
Since you `set size square`, there will be for *sure* an "unwanted" left and right margin.

What you can do to at least minimize the margins is to set the terminal size to square size as well, e.g. to 3 x 3 inches.
However, keep in mind the graph size is square but x and y axes have tics and labels which require space depending on numbers and labels which might be different for x and y.

```
set term epslatex standalone size 3 in, 3 in
```

From `help latex`:

> Syntax:

```
  set terminal {latex | emtex} {default | {courier|roman} {<fontsize>}}
               {size <XX>{unit}, <YY>{unit}} {rotate | norotate}
```

> By default the plot will inherit font settings from the embedding
>   document. You have the option of forcing either Courier (cmtt) or
>   Roman (cmr) fonts instead. In this case you may also specify a
>   fontsize. Unless your driver is capable of building fonts at any size
>   (e.g. dvips), stick to the standard 10, 11 and 12 point sizes. 
>   ...

Maybe, there are LaTeX commands to crop the graph to its bounding box.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. but I was not super-satisfied with the part that the font size is dependent on the image size. It works with "N inches times N inches", but the font size changes with N...

Comment: Have you checked `help latex`? At least it says that you should be able to fix the font size.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AlainMarigot help, I change the system to Lua tikz with the option `tightboundingbox`.
Looks good, but not exactly same as `epslatex`.

[image]